# Publish app only for 3.2+ tablets and 2.2+ handsets?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Is it possible to declare application to be compatibile for ALL handsets running 2.2+, and ALL tablets running on 3.2+ ? So actually tablets lower than 3.2 are exluded.

Comment: What do you mean by 2.2+ and 3.2+ ? Please clearly explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to publish multiple apps with different filters.  There is a quick walkthrough in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) that describes how to do this.  (scroll to the bottom of the page)